# Google Column chart with 3 values - SQL

Tags: php, sql, charts, google-visualization

I need to create this chart (below) with 3 bars, but my code appears to be all right but it is not working, what can I be doing wrong?

I can't return anything on my chart, it is blank

[enter image description here][1]
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SlLp.png

```
 <?php
     $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','----','----','----');
    ?>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Data_de_Solicitação', 'andamento', 'concluido', 'total'],

               <?php 

            $query = "SELECT COUNT(Status) AS andamento
        FROM demandas_portal
        WHERE Status = 'Em Andamento'";

          $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(Status) AS concluido
        FROM demandas_portal
        WHERE Status = 'Concluído'";

          $query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM demandas_portal";



         $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query,$query2,$query3);
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

         echo "['".$row['Data_de_Solicitação']."',".$row['andamento'].",".$row['concluido'].",".$row['total']."],";
         }
         ?> 

            ]);

            var options = {
              chart: {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
              }
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you right click the page and view source, will you please share the data that is generated from the php? also, please check for errors in the browser's console (press F12)

Comment: What your php variables $query, $query2, $query3 are supposed to contain? And what do they really contain? Please, isolate first if this is a php problem or a javascript (google chart) problem